# Request library not found - theHarvester.py

Tags: python, python-2.7, penetration-testing

I am newish to programming and following a tutorial on IT security which uses a python utility called theHarvester to gather email accounts and domains for penetration testing purposes.

I have python 2.7.10 installed on my OS and I have cloned the latest version of theHarvestor from GitHub and cd into it within Terminal.

Problem: When I try and run the program using the command:

```
python TheHarvester.py
```

I get an error which states "request library not found, please install it before proceeding"

Does this suggest that I need to download further libraries from python i.e. (Pip etc)

I would be grateful for some steering as how I can make this run.

[image: TERMINAL]

Comment: On pretty much on every project you will see dependencies listed if there are any, you can see requests listed on the first page  https://github.com/laramies/theHarvester and how to install it.

Comment: Posting the image of your screen is a very bad practice.  You can easily copy the text, and paste it here for completeness and for better visibility for those who don't like tiny green dots on black backgrounds!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you examine the [source code](https://github.com/laramies/theHarvester/blob/master/theHarvester.py) you will see that it requires the `requests` library (there is a typo in the error message):

```
try:
    import requests
except:
    print "Request library not found, please install it before proceeding\n"
    sys.exit()
```

so, install `requests` using `pip` first:

```
pip install requests
```

Comment: Hi, when is use pip install requests in terminal and try and run it, I get an error saying bad interpreter

Comment: You should quote the message completely, but if you are not running as root you need to elevate yourself.  Are you on Ubuntu or some other linux distro?  Try: sudo pip install requests

Comment: mac os.sudo pip install requests doesn't do the trick. it returns "unable to execute /usr/local/bin/pip: No such file or directory"

Comment: You have an old symlink, reinstall pip

Comment: No worries, the  bad interpreter is basically the same issue, you must have deleted the python interpreter and the symlink remains.

Comment: padraic that seems to have me on track, its saying I have pip version 7.1.2 and its stating that 8.1.1 is available, should I migrate to 8.1.1

Comment: @ChrisDormani, yep it is no harm to be up to date, you can `pip install -U pip` to update pip itself adding sudo if necessary

Answer (score 1):

According to documentation this project has deps:

Requests library (http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/)

So, solution is:

```
pip install requests
```